# angular-cli adding webpack tasks to copy dist files

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli, I need to copy the files in the "dist" folder to another folder as part of a task.  I understand angular-cli uses webpack, how do I include a task to copy the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently AngularCLI does not expose the Webpack config to the end user of the CLI.

You can either:

- Add an NPM script that runs `ng build` then copies the output to the folder you want
- Or set the folder you want as the output folder in `angular-cli.json`

  The `dist` folder is configurable. You can change the `outDir` property in `angular-cli.json`, or add a `-o` argument to the `ng serve` or `ng build` command each time you run it (and again, you can store that in `package.json` as an npm script)

Comment: Can I give multiple output paths?

Comment: No, you cannot.